# Паттерн для разработки инди - игры

Tags: unity3d, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу написать свою игру в Unity3D, но чтобы в ней было все логично и хоть с какой-то архитектурой + не было слишком сложно расширять функционал игры. **Какие есть подходы или паттерны для этого?**

Возможно поможет концепт игры:

Сингл плеерный рогалик с такой схемой уровней: для выполнения главного квеста нужно выполнить несколько сопутствующих [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2luhwy3KAE0

Comment: `spaghetti code pattern!`